# Install Ubuntu on Lenovo G580

Tags: 12.04, windows-8, laptop, lenovo

Can I install Ubuntu on a Lenovo G580, but keeping Windows 8? How?

The specs are:

```
Prossesor: Intel® Core™ i5-3210M (3M Cache, 2.50 GHz)
Ram: 4.0GB PC3-12800 DDR3 SDRAM 1600 MHz
OS: Windows 8 64bits
HDD: 720gb
```

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install Ubuntu in dual boot with windows 8. For dual boot i prefer you need a partition of 20GB less will also work and start installing ubuntu in that partion from boot sector and just follow the instructions. It's easy